# I want to get the options dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, forms, for-loop, dynamic

When I submit a form, I want to get the option's value using a for loop, and I have this code. How can I successfully get this module working?

```
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            String gender = Request.Form['"Option"+i'].ToString();
            Response.Write(gender);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you just want:

```
String gender = Request.Form["Option" + i].ToString();
```

The fact that it's an indexer argument is irrelevant here. It's just like this:

```
int x = 5;
String y = "Option" + x; // Now y is "Option5"
```

Looking at your loop, however, you probably *actually* want to use `j` rather than `i`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

The value of `i` doesn't change over the course of your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String gender = Request.Form["Option" + j].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    string key = string.Format("Option{0}", i);
    string gender = Request.Form[key].ToString();
    Response.Write(gender);
}
```

However, because of the way your `for`-loop is written it will just output the same form field `i` times. You probably want something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < totalFields; j++)
{
    string key = string.Format("Option{0}", j);
    string gender = Request.Form[key].ToString();
    Response.Write(gender);
}
```

Comment: Why bother using `string.Format` when simple concatenation will work?

Comment: @JonSkeet sure you can just use concatenation, too. I prefer to not use concatenation. You could more easily abstract the format of the `key` later if you had to -- the call is the same whether the format is `Option{0}` or `{0}Option` or `Option{0}_new`, etc. With concatenation, you'd have to modify how you concatenate the string.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: That sounds like premature generalization to me. It's *really* not hard to change that later, and it would be a completely localized change.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree that it's not necessary. This is just how it struck me to answer the question. If I had seen this question on another day (when I hadn't just gotten finished with rewriting bugged code that used string concatenation) I might have answered it differently :)